# Before and After animation to input submit element

Tags: html, css, forms, form-submit, contact-form

I have an animation to an **input field** which stays 'on top' of it and the **submit** is no longer active. **z-index** is no helpful.

It is possible to make it work?

Please note that **aspire-contact** is the class of the form.

**HTML**

```
<div class="aspire-contact-wrapper">
    <input value="SUBMIT" id="submit-button" class="aspire-contact-submit" type="submit">
</div>
```

My **CSS** code

```
input.aspire-contact-submit{    
color: #fff;
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
z-index: 9999;}

.aspire-contact{
position: relative;}

.aspire-contact-wrapper{
border: 2px solid #fff!important;
display: inline-block;
padding: 33px 11px;
border-radius: 50%;
margin-top: 40px;
z-index: 10;}

.aspire-contact-wrapper:before {
content: '';
width: 96px;
height: 96px;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid #fff;
border-radius: 100%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -48px;
bottom: 5%;
margin-bottom: -22px;
display: inline-block;
-webkit-animation: doublePulsation 1.9s ease infinite;
animation: doublePulsation 1.9s ease infinite;
z-index: 10;}

@-webkit-keyframes doublePulsation {
 0% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.0, 1.0); opacity: 0.0;}
50% {opacity: 0.55;}
100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3); opacity: 0.0;} }

@keyframes doublePulsation {
 0% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.0, 1.0); opacity: 0.0;}
50% {opacity: 0.55;}
100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3); opacity: 0.0;} }
```

Comment: Where is your actual z-index transition - nothing in your css shows you animating the z-index.  Also both your wrapper and button aren't positioned, so the z-index won't apply anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try using `z-index: -10;` for `.aspire-contact-wrapper:before`

And also better make `.aspire-contact-wrapper` be `position:relative`, as you are positioning the absolute element within it :)

Comment: Well, thank you Den. I had position relative to the .aspire-contact, and simply didn't put it to wrapper when created it.. my bad, now I know.

Comment: @IoanaS You are welcome.
Here is good article about positioning:

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/